# comparing list with string

Tags: python, comparison

lettersGuessed is a list of letters

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
  listA = {'a','b','c','p','o','e','p','l'}
  abc = "apple"
```

now if (some or all of)  the letters guessed in the list (listA) are INCLUDED in all the letters (Chars) in the string, then it is supposed to return a true boolean...

but everytime I do this question I keep on getting a false return...even though the above example should CLEARLY return "true"

so can any1 out there help me please?

Thnx a lot!!!

Comment: listA is a set not a list

Comment: The above example shouldn't clearly return anything, since it doesn't even have a  `return` statement. You seem to have forgotten to include what you've tried.

Comment: `return len(listA.intersection(set(abc))) > 0`

Comment: @MrE -- Note that the method form `s.intersection` doesn't need to be passed a `set`.  You could do:  `my_set.intersection(my_list)` and it still works!  Neat!

Comment: Ah, nice :) I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

you could do something like:

```
abc = 'apple'
setA = {'a','b','c','p','o','e','p','l'}
sabc = set(abc) 
print len(sabc) == len(sabc & setA)
```

Of course, this is a little misleading.  What do you want to happen in the case where `setA = { 'a','p','l','e' }`?  This will still return `True` as the duplicates are not accounted for.  If you need to account for duplicates, I would recommend a `Collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def compare(word,guesses):
    return Counter(word) <= Counter(guesses)
```

This works because it makes sure that the count of the letters in `word` is always less than the count of the corresponding letter in guesses.

Comment: You can compare Counter objects too: `Counter("apple") <= Counter("apple and more")` gives True, but `Counter("apple") <= Counter("aple")` gives False.

Comment: @DSM -- My original comparison was wrong anyway.  I fixed it up so that it works now, but your comparison seems to be a good bit cleaner.  Who knew Counters were so useful! :)

Comment: If 'aple' is not a correct guess, this is the right answer. The OP did not specify if 'aple' is false, but 'apple' is true. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use sets:

```
>>> set('apple')<{'a','b','c','p','o','e','p','l'}
True
>>> set('abc')<{'a','b','c','p','o','e','p','l'}
True
```

The `<` [compares set 1 as being a complete subset of set 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

But, as noted by @mgilson, this is not accurate for strings with duplicates.

Use a counter as he suggests.

Comment: I like your set example more than mine.  The problem with sets is the inability to account for duplicates.

Comment: (I upvoted this btw ... Hopefully I can remember the operator/methods for `issubset` and `issuperset` in the future :) +1

Comment: def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):

    lg = "".join(lettersGuessed)
    sw = "".join(secretWord)
    return not bool([c for c in sw if c not in lg])

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `any`:

```
>>> letters_guessed = 'abc'
>>> letters_in_word = 'abcdefghi'
>>> any(letter for letter in letters_guessed if letter in letters_in_word)
True
>>> letters_guessed = 'zzz'
>>> any(letter for letter in letters_guessed if letter in letters_in_word)
False
```

Comment: well amigos...this is what i did and it ended up being correct!

Answer (score 0):

As someone said, your post sample doesn't return anything.  Here is something I came up with, but it isn't as elegant as the others.

```
actualWord = "apple"
guessList = ["a","b","c","e","l"]

def WordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    listSW = list(secretWord)
    answer = True
    for item in listSW:
        if item not in lettersGuessed:
            answer = False
            break
    return answer

print WordGuessed(actualWord,guessList)
```